# Using ST_ClosestPoint, ST_StartPoint, and ST_EndPoint to find closest object to beginning and end points of lines

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, closest-points

I need to find the closest points to either end of a line using geometry from two separate tables. So far I was able to use the following to find the geometry of the end points:

```
SELECT "id", ST_StartPoint(dmp.geom) AS upstream,
       ST_EndPoint(dmp.geom) AS downstream
FROM sewers.pipes,
        LATERAL ST_Dump("geom") AS dmp
;
```

Using this, I want to use `ST_ClosestPoint` to find structures that are the closest to the end points of pipes. This is what I've come up with so far:

```
SELECT ST_ClosestPoint('POINT(SELECT ST_StartPoint(dmp.geom) AS upstream
FROM sewers.pipes,
        LATERAL ST_Dump("geom") AS dmp)',
                      ('LINESTRING(SELECT geom from sewers.pipes)'))
```

However, this gives the following error:

```
ERROR: parse error - invalid geometry
Line 1: SELECT ST_ClosestPoint('POINT(SELECT ST_STartPoint(dmp.geom)...

HINT: "POINT(SE" <-- parse error at position 8 within geometry
SQL state: XX000
Character: 24
```

I have provided some sample data below.

sewers.pipes <-- these are the lines

```
| id       | geom |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 822      | 0105000020950B00000100000001020000000200000046243EC3282608418D28242D6C1B3D4128531BE88A2608418284B3EF561B3D41        |
| 6660     | 0105000020950B0000010000000102000000020000004ABF2CBC86B108413B93650696323D413C487924CCB10841925D490495323D41            |
```

sewers.structures <-- these are points

```
| id        | geom |
| --------  | -------------- |
| 2014      | 0104000020950B00000100000001010000001026FA48113B07410D6A8412CF1D3D41            |
| 22979     | 0104000020950B0000010000000101000000BA1BF246E6DD0741D064CB58C2E43C41            |
```

I know that there may be an error that comes from selecting multiple data points, eg. `more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`, so that may be an issue as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I am confused. Which points you want to get the closest to the first and last points of your linestring? Can you provide a data sample?

Comment: @JimJones I added some more clarity. I also attempted to use a markdown table to add some sample data. My goal is to find the closest structure (point) to a given endpoint of a pipe (linestring).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with distinct `LATERAL`s for `upstream` and `downstream`:

```
SELECT p.id,
  (dump_line).geom,
  ST_EndPoint((dump_line).geom) AS downstream,
  geom_closest_downstream,
  ST_StartPoint((dump_line).geom) AS upstream,
  geom_closest_upstream
FROM sewers.pipes p,
  LATERAL ST_Dump(p.geom) dump_line,
  LATERAL (SELECT s.geom 
           FROM sewers.structures s
           ORDER BY ST_EndPoint((dump_line).geom)<->s.geom 
           LIMIT 1) j (geom_closest_downstream),
  LATERAL (SELECT s.geom 
           FROM sewers.structures s
           ORDER BY ST_StartPoint((dump_line).geom)<->s.geom 
           LIMIT 1) i (geom_closest_upstream);
```

- To access the geometries from `ST_Dump` you have to wrap its output with parenthesis, e.g. `(ST_Dump(multiline)).geom`
- The operator `<->` at the `ORDER BY` clause corresponds to distance. So, using it combined with a `LIMIT 1` you get only the closest distance.

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b024e468c192f16a362574961665effa)

Comment: When I ran this, it gave me empty columns for downstream and upstream, so it returned the same value for all geom_closest_downstream and geom_closest_upstream.

Comment: @AThomspon did you check my fiddle? I added it in my last edit

Comment: I checked the demo, and while it works on the demo database, I am getting an error stating "Operation on mixed SRID geometries." I used 'ST_SetSRID()' to force the 'ST_Dump()' to 4326, but the error persists.

Comment: @AThomspon why are you using `4326`? Your geometries are encoded with `2965` ;)

Comment: @AThomspon I'm glad I could help. I just noticed you have `multilinestrings` and `multipoints`, both always with a single geometry. In case your table does not have multiple geometries in a single row, consider using `point` and `linestring`.  It would make the query a bit easier ;) cheers and happy coding